# the error or broken page not directing to 404 page

Tags: html

On a 404 page for my website, I'am having .htaccess file in the root directory where am using this rule

```
ErrorDocument 404 www.abc.com/404.html

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff          .woff
AddType application/font-woff            .woff
AddType application/font-woff2           .woff2
```

Thought the fonts type are working without throwing any error, the 404.html is not working.

Am i missing something

Comment: Thanks Darren for formatting

Comment: Try simply: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

Comment: After implementing i am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Does the file (404.html) exist at web root?

Comment: Do you really have a subdirectory called `www.abc.com`?

Comment: yes there is a file 404.html in the root directory

Comment: Does your webserver has access to the file? Check the owner user (it  must be www-data or somthing like that) and the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apache [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html):

> - A local URL to redirect to (if the action begins with a "/").
> - An external URL to redirect to (if the action is a valid URL).
> - Text to be displayed (if none of the above). The text must be wrapped    in quotes (") if it consists of more than one word.

I think you missed the protocol part from the URL. As Darren suggests you can use absolute paths too on your server.